# in windows service storing datetime in MYSQL database exception

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, datetime

i will be tested the application as windows application then it will be stored the datetime in MySQL data base.when i will be start this application using windows service it will be thrown this exception.

```
error [HY000][MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver] [MySqlid -6.0.11-alpha-community]incorrect datetime value '5/6/2011 9:00:00 AM' for column column-name at row1"
```

windows application take the system format & my system format is `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss`
in windows service which format is used.

```
 string dt1 = Convert.ToString(DateTime.FromFileTime(e.sts[counter].TimeStamp));
Datetime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(dt1,"MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

i will be checked the date format of the MYSQL write this code but it will be display the unrecognized string format

Comment: first check the datetime format for the mysql

Answer (score 0):

If you are recording the time of the windows service event as it happens then I would use the MySQL [NOW()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) function in your query.